# Refresh ui-Dialog popups in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have 6 ui-dialog popups same class name. If I open 2 or more popups, its not refreshing.

For example first popup name is "text 1". And second is, "text 2" same as "text 3".

First I am going to open "text 1" dialog. Without closing this, if I open the "Text 2" dialog, I want to refresh the "text 2" dialog without reloading the page. Only dialog refresh. Same as If I open n number of dialogs, I want to refresh all each dialogs. Please help me how can I do this in jquery or javascript. I tried the following ways. But it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});


$(".ui-dialog").reload();

$(".ui-dialog").refresh();

$("ui-dialog").dialog("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery.each, like

```
$(".ui-dialog").each(function(){
   // do whatever you want there.
   $(this).reload();
});
```